# Password protecting Wordpress; all but front page?

Tags: php, wordpress, password-protection

I found this code to password protect the pages in my WP site. However, I do not know where to put the code? In the Theme I am using? What page? Thanks!

```
<?php
if (is_user_logged_in() || is_home()){
    echo "Welcome, registered user, here are my lovely posts";
}
else {
    header( 'Location: http://www.yoursite.com/wp-login.php' ) ;
};
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Need to know more about the file structure of your theme. WP themes differ greatly from theme to theme.

However,

putting that code **anywhere** in a page that is executed by the server should produce the desired result, it just would be preferrable (and more server friendly) to put this at the top of the execution layer as then any code below would not have to be executed by the server.

Answer (score 0):

This would probably work if you put it in your theme's `functions.php` file.  It check whether they are on the home page (blog page) or front page (static front page).  If not, they are directed to the login page.  I assume the front page is open to all, so you wouldn't want to give them a "Welcome, registered user" if they aren't registered.

```
<?php
if ( !is_home() || !is_front_page() ) {
    if ( is_user_logged_in() ){
        echo "Welcome, registered user, here are my lovely posts";
    }
    else {
        header( 'Location: http://www.yoursite.com/wp-login.php' ) ;
    };
}
?>
```